# Scikit-learn Isolation Forest: Any way to extract the path lengths?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, isolation-forest

I'm using an IsolationForest classifier in my script and I'd like to extract some information for each prediction, such as the path lenght, which refers to the number of edges an observation must pass in the tree from the root to the terminal node. It's used in calculating the anomaly score. Would anyone know how to get that value (not the anomaly score)?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?